# Where Should I Put Rake Tasks Used In Multiple Projects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, rake-task

Now that I've been using rake for a while, I am finding I have certain utility tasks which I use in multiple Rails projects. These are tasks that are configured using environmental variables or through passing in parameters.

Obviously I would like these tasks to sit somewhere centrally so I don't have multiple copies to keep in sync if I update or add anything.

Where should i put these shared tasks and how should I share them between my projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a ruby gem containing your rake tasks and then include that gem into each of your projects.

Comment: Fair enough. Thought there might be global directory or similar.